# How to use linq to filter to the max of a group

Tags: linq, search

I have this list

```
var commonContractsList = (
        from i in referredDilutions
        join f in dilutionsList
            on i.Contract equals f.Contract
        select f)
    .ToList();
```

The list `commonContractsList` has several fields and three in particular, `contract`, `instalment` and `amount`. We can have several `instalment`s for one `contract`. Every `contract`/`instalment` has an `amount`.

Now, what I want to do is get, for each `contract`, a list of all records of `contract`s where the `instalment` has the higher `amount`.

> **Source Data**
>
> ```
> contract    instalment    amount
> 1           1             100
> 1           2             1000
> 2           1             100
> 3           1             1000
> 4           1             200
> 4           2             100
> 5           1             1000
> ```

So i need,

> **Results**
>
> ```
> contract    instalment    amount
> 1           2             1000
> 2           1             100
> 3           1             1000
> 4           1             200
> 5           1             1000
> ```

My knowledge of linq is limited and I'm having a hard time with project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should give you the expected results:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { contract = 1, installment =  1, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 1, installment =  2, amount = 1000},
    new { contract = 2, installment =  1, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 3, installment =  1, amount = 1000},
    new { contract = 4, installment =  1, amount = 200},
    new { contract = 4, installment =  2, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 5, installment =  1, amount = 1000},
};

var result = from d in data
             group d by d.contract into g
             let highestInstallment = (from x in g
                                       orderby x.amount descending
                                       select x).First()
             select new
             {
                 contract = g.Key,
                 installment = highestInstallment.installment,
                 amount = highestInstallment.amount
             };
```

You group by `contract` and then within each group you check for the highest amount. I've added the `let` clause so you don't have to repeat the sub query for both `installment` and `amount`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the accepted answer for those who looks for minimalist examples:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { contract = 1, installment =  1, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 1, installment =  2, amount = 1000},
    new { contract = 2, installment =  1, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 3, installment =  1, amount = 1000},
    new { contract = 4, installment =  1, amount = 200},
    new { contract = 4, installment =  2, amount = 100},
    new { contract = 5, installment =  1, amount = 1000},
};
```

This gives the same result (no need in additional select):

```
var result1 = from d in data
            group d by d.contract
            into g
            select (from x in g
                    orderby x.amount descending
                    select x).First();
```

The same written by a Linq method chain (one line of code):

```
var result2 = data.GroupBy(d => d.contract).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.amount).First() );
```

The accepted answer  rewritten as method chain (many code anyway, but let it be here)

```
var result3 = data.GroupBy(d => d.contract)
                .Select(g => new {g, highestInstallment = (g.OrderByDescending(x => x.amount)).First()})
                .Select(@t => new
                {
                    contract = @t.g.Key,
                    installment = @t.highestInstallment.installment,
                    amount = @t.highestInstallment.amount
                });
```